# git 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository when pushing to remote

Tags: git

I created a bare repository and cloned it. In my cloned repository I made a commit. Now I'm trying to push this commit back to the repository I cloned from, which is defined as remote:

```
git remote -v
origin: ssh://user@server.com/some/path/barerepo (fetch)
origin: ssh://user@server.com/some/path/barerepo (push)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: '/some/path/barerepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**
The problem was that some file inside barerepo folder didn't have execute permission. What file needs this permission?

Comment: Your git repo seems to have double colons, `ssh::` vs `ssh:`

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is typo. I made an edit

Comment: Why did you clone instead of fetching from it at first point?

Comment: First, what is the output of "git pull"? Second, if that succeeds, try cloning again (to a differen directory).  The error message usually means the remote repo just isn't there, so make sure it is.

Comment: The problem was that some file inside barerepo folder didn't have execute permission. Do you know what file needs this permission?

Comment: @Maximus: If there was a permission error, that means that something (other than Git) modified the files in the repo, which you should do your best to prevent. (Unless you *really* know what you're doing.)

Comment: I don't think any files require execute permissions besides hooks. All of the folders, on the other hand, need execute permissions, in UNIX you cannot change the current working directory if the folder does not have execute permissions.